# Can I assign a id to a drawable, which I construct programmatically?

Tags: android

A drawable, which was created by XML, can be referenced in code by

```
    R.drawable.my_drawable
```

So, I assume that drawables do have a resource id.

When I look through the docs, i cant find a method:

```
    myDrawable.setId(id)
```

So, though I can construct a drawable in code, i dont see how I can assign a id to a drawable, which I created in code?

Comment: Why do you need to assign an id to the drawable? R.drawable.* is already a unique identifier to that resource.

Comment: because I create a ShapeDrawable in code, so no xml file exists.

Comment: Could you provide an example use case?

Answer (score -3):

`R.drawable.my_drawable` is the unique id that android automatically generates for your drawable -- theres no need to set it, and if you need to reference it, the constant `R.drawable.my_drawable` works.

Comment: If I interpret mradlmaier's question correctly he wants to know how to set the ID of a drawable that he has generated in code, e.g. a BitmapDrawable.

Comment: Then your solution is incorrect... `BitmapDrawable` doesn't extend `View` and doesn't have a `setId` method.

Comment: deleted my answer to @hanspeide, because he deleted his. :)

Comment: You're right. Seems that I overlooked that mradlmaier was talking about a drawable. As that is the case I agree with your answer, and have deleted mine. Upvoted.

Comment: this is exactly what I meant. Although, if created in by xml file, drawables have resource ids, there is no method to set the id of a drawable which was created by code, similiar to a View.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for... what do you need the id for?

Comment: @Benoir: to pass it as a parameter to the setInt (int viewId, String methodName, int value) method of a RemoteView, with methodName "setBackgroundResource". I can not use setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable), because there is no setter method for that in RemoteView. Alterntively I could build the complete layout tree (downwards from the parent of the layout having the drawable as background) at runtime from scratch and use the addView (int viewId, RemoteViews nestedView) of RemoteView. Sounds nasty and I dont know if it would work either. Just want to modify the drawable of a RemoteView.

Comment: the `setBackgoundResource` takes `R.drawable.my_drawable` as the id parameter. Thats the id I was referring to.

Comment: @Benoir: As there is no XML file my_drawable.xml, (only a in code with new GradientDrawable() constructed), there is no R.drawable.my_drawable. While drawables which do exist at design-time have an id, drawables constructed at runtime do not have an id, neither is there a method to assign a id to a drawble. It may not be obvious, but a View can be assigned an id at runtime, drawables however not. Though both can have a id if they exist as xml-files at design-time and the android:id attribute is set. That is the problem.

Comment: @mradlmaier... with all due respect you're not listening to me... android automatically generated an `R.drawable.my_drawable` id for any image that is in the res/drawable folder. Just copy your image to res/drawable and then you can access its id using `R.drawable.image_name`

Comment: @Benoir, I am really not getting it. How would I copy a drawable which exists only in code, to the res/drawable folder?

Comment: @Benoir, I tested the alternative (build the views tree from scratch, see above) with a normal activity (not a remote view yet) and within an activity it works fine, though it was a bit of work to code the equivalent of xml in code. Lets see if it works in a remoteview, too. Then I would not need the id.

Comment: @Benoir: it does not work. I posted a new question with all details. It really bugs me, because I have seen many widgets which are configurable on-the-fly and to such an extent that I doubt they are based on huge collections of resource files. For example, widgets which allow the user to choose any baclgroundcolor with a color picker. Here is the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037196/why-is-android-trying-to-read-an-xml-layout-file-from-the-res-layout-when-i-hav